# Scala web app to talk to cloud instance?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

If I'm using Play! to build a scala web app, how can I connect to a remote instance, run a map reduce job there? I have the scripts for the map reduce job, just not sure how I can connect to the instance within play and run the map reduce job on the instance using parameter data I get from the user through the web app?

Comment: I think you are much to vague to get any help with this. Try to describe more detailed what it is you want to do, what cloud, what kind of app, platform - is it another play app, is it a scala app, is it something else...

Comment: @johanandren It's a Play Scala app that takes in parameters for a script, then I want to talk to my machine on the cloud and have it run scripts with those parameters from the web UI.